# CloudFront can't use S3 Website origin, only REST origin Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to automate spinning up a CloudFront distribution with S3 origin.  I'd like to set the origin to the S3 website URL, e.g. `mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.  So, I thought my Cloudformation template should look like this:

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
"Resources" : {
    "myDistribution" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
        "Properties" : {
            "DistributionConfig" : {
                "Origins" : [ {
                    "DomainName" : "mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                    "Id" : "myS3Origin",
...
```

However that yields the following error:

*The parameter Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid S3 bucket.*

Which is true, so I can specify the S3 bucket.  But I want my origin to be the website endpoint.  My non-automated workaround is to deploy with the S3 REST endpoint and update the origin in the UI after.

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
"Resources" : {
    "myDistribution" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
        "Properties" : {
            "DistributionConfig" : {
                "Origins" : [ {
                    "DomainName" : "mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com",
                    "Id" : "myS3Origin",
...
```

According to the docs:

*The DNS name of the Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) bucket or the HTTP server from which you want CloudFront to get objects for this origin.*

I can't find anything about a website endpoint origin.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-origin.html#cfn-cloudfront-origin-originpath

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you've included quite all the relevant parts of your configuration.

The issue here is that an origin that is an S3 website hosting endpoint is not an S3 origin -- it's a *custom origin*.

Anything other than the REST endpoint of a bucket is always a custom origin.

Comment: Thanks! This led me to my eventual answer, sorry for the formatting; you deserve credit.  "Resources": {
    "CloudFrontDistribution": {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
      "DependsOn": "S3RedirectBucket",
      "Properties" : {
        "DistributionConfig" : {
          "Origins" : [
            {
              "DomainName": "mysite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
              "Id": "MyWebsiteOrigin",
              "CustomOriginConfig" : {
                "HTTPPort": 80,
                "HTTPSPort": 443,
                "OriginProtocolPolicy": "http"